# Run ansible-playbook in Jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, ansible

Question: Is it possible to have a docker-compose file to run ansible-playbook in a Jenkins container?

Summary:
I have a Jenkins container (containerA) that I would like to run ansible-playbook. However, since the containers stop after the execution, I don't know how to define a non-running container in docker-compose.

I have posted the output for `docker ps -a`, the `docker-compose` and the Dockerfile for `ansible-playbook`

Please let me know if my question is unclear.
PG

```
root@jenkins1:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                                   NAMES
c47a4ee06d71        jenkins/jenkins     "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months               0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8443/tcp   jenkins1
956309ae7370        foo/ansible       "ansible-playbook"       2 months ago        Exited (2) 2 months ago                                                                           hopeful_hypatia

cat /opt/docker_jenkins/docker-compose.yml
version: '3.2'
services:
  jenkins:
    restart: always
    image: 'jenkins/jenkins'
    container_name: jenkins1
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
      - '50000:50000'
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: jenkins_home
        target: /var/jenkins_home
        volume:
          nocopy: true
      - type: bind
        source: /var/lib/bin
        target: /root/.local/bin

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

```
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV ANSIBLE_VERSION 2.8.6

ENV BUILD_PACKAGES \
  bash \
  curl \
  tar \
  openssh-client \
  sshpass \
  git \
  python \
  py-boto \
  py-dateutil \
  py-httplib2 \
  py-jinja2 \
  py-paramiko \
  py-pip \
  py-yaml \
  ca-certificates

# If installing ansible@testing
#RUN \
#   echo "@testing http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> #/etc/apk/repositories

RUN set -x && \
    \
    echo "==> Adding build-dependencies..."  && \
    apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies \
      gcc \
      musl-dev \
      libffi-dev \
      openssl-dev \
      python-dev && \
    \
    echo "==> Upgrading apk and system..."  && \
    apk update && apk upgrade && \
    \
    echo "==> Adding Python runtime..."  && \
    apk add --no-cache ${BUILD_PACKAGES} && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install python-keyczar docker-py && \
    \
    echo "==> Installing Ansible..."  && \
    pip install ansible==${ANSIBLE_VERSION} && \
    \
    echo "==> Cleaning up..."  && \
    apk del build-dependencies && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    \
    echo "==> Adding hosts for convenience..."  && \
    mkdir -p /etc/ansible /ansible && \
    echo "[local]" >> /etc/ansible/hosts && \
    echo "localhost" >> /etc/ansible/hosts

ENV ANSIBLE_GATHERING smart
ENV ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING false
ENV ANSIBLE_RETRY_FILES_ENABLED false
ENV ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH /ansible/playbooks/roles
ENV ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING True
ENV PYTHONPATH /ansible/lib
ENV PATH /ansible/bin:$PATH
ENV ANSIBLE_LIBRARY /ansible/library

WORKDIR /ansible/playbooks

ENTRYPOINT ["ansible-playbook"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the docker container will be up only if there is any process or service that is holding that container to run.

In your docker file you are executing `ansible-playbook` command this will error out stating `ERROR! You must specify a playbook file to run` along with the help options.

If you want to execute ansible playbook you have to pass more arguments

A successful playbook execution happens like.

```
ansible-playbook -i <inventory_file> <playbook_name>
```

Comment: Even on a successful run, it will eventually exits. That would not change the fact that will exit. Leaving next run to fail because the container is not running anymore...

Comment: yes...isn't that what you need...execute the task and exit ? why do you need the container to be up always ?

Comment: they way you should execute ansible from jenkins should be via dynamic slaves..and not running ansible always..the work of slaves should be just to execute and then terminate

Comment: If the ansible container exited -  How would the Jenkins container able to communicate or reference it? 

This is the part I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: That's the essence you to use dynamic slaves provisioning in jenkins. Since you are running jenkins as a container you can use docker in docker for the dynamic slaves...

https://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/

https://github.com/tehranian/dind-jenkins-slave

The above links might help

Comment: Sorry for the late reply as I get caught up from operation work. I will try those tonight, these appears to be what I am looking for!